# Failing to glue MultipartEntityBuilder with @ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring

I am performing an http post using the [Apache libs](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient) with form data. This is how the entity is being created:

```
HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
      .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
      .addTextBody("field1", field1, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      .addTextBody("field2", field2, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      .addTextBody("fieldN", fieldN, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      .build();
```

And the actual post:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(endpoint);
httpPost.setEntity(httpEntity);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(setHeaders(httpPost));
httpPost.releaseConnection();
```

The controller:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> myController(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorizationHeader,
                                                       @PathVariable("someVar") String someVar,
                                                       @ModelAttribute MyDTO myDTO) throws Exception {
```

And finally the DTO:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class MyDTO {
   @NotEmpty(message = "some message")
   private String field1;
   private String field2;
   //...
   private String fieldN;
}
```

A few fields may end up being empty but I am making sure that `field1` (the only one yielding `@NotEmpty`) is never empty. My problem is that all myDTO fields arrive empty in the controller.

Does anyone know what I am missing? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I neglected to include the header settings in my question which ended up being the actual cause for this particular problem. I am posting this answer in case someone else makes the same mistake:

```
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
```

This cannot be the content type, removing it worked for me.